# How do I change my name in CS:GO?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to create a mini montage on CS:GO by using GOTV and my old Steam name shows up in-game. How can I get CS:GO to use my current Steam name?

Comment: Try restarting Steam?

Comment: It should update your in-game name to your steamname instantly. Restart Steam/CSGO, or change your name again to see if that will help?

Comment: Are you trying to change the name displayed from a demo file (which will display the name you had at the time the demo was made)?

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your name and not Steam update, restart the game and Steam, must automatically be changed.